# How do I replace unique values from another array, by replacing the original array

Tags: javascript

So I have two sets of Array, one of them is an object (`arrA`). And another one is just a set of primitive values `arrB`.

```js
let a = "100229265852737908723455202093346882084130103685642861644052656467061936958706";
let arrA = [];
let arrB = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
  arrA.push({index: i, pos: i, unique: false});
  arrB.push(i);
}

let b = a.split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/).slice(0, 28);
b.forEach((val, index) => {
  let c = Math.floor((+val / 100) * 28 ) + 1;
  
  if (arrB.indexOf(c) !== -1) {
    arrB.splice(arrB.indexOf(c), 1);
    arrA[index].unique = true;
  }
  arrA[index].pos = c;
});

arrB.forEach((val, index) => {
  arrA.forEach((valA, indexA) => {
    if (!valA.unique) {
      if (arrB[index] > valA.pos) {
        arrA[indexA].pos = arrB[index];
        arrA[indexA].unique = true;
        arrB.splice(arrB.indexOf(arrB[index]));
      }
    }
  })
});
```

My expected result is, `arrA.pos` is:

`3, 1, 9, 8, 17, 15, 21, 4, 22, 10, 16, 6, 7, 27, 13, 20, 25, 5, 12, 14, 19, 11, 24, 18, 26, 28, 2`

However I got:

`3, 1, 9, 8, 17, 15, 21, 4, 21, 10, 16, 6, 6, 27, 10, 20, 23, 3, 12, 9, 3, 11, 24, 18, 8, 18, 18`

Comment: `arrA` is *not* an Object. Rather an Array of Objects

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to split the string into an Array of digits, each 2 characters in length, then get just the unique values from that Array?

Comment: Can you please add comment to your code and explain it very carefully

Comment: @somewhatsapient yes. That's the first forEach loop. The second forEach loop, I am trying to replace all duplicates, by using arrB. The array of objects, has a field called pos, which contains duplicate values, and it is going to be replaced if the arrA.pos > arrB[index]

Comment: What is your end result, and what are you doing with each loop?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to take the string, split it into an array of elements of an arbitrary length, each being a 2-digit number, then output an Array that contains only the original Array's unique values, then you can do this:

```
const MAGIC_NUMBER = 28;
const a = "100229265852737908723455202093346882084130103685642861644052656467061936958706";
const b = a.split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/).slice(0, MAGIC_NUMBER );

const unique = Array.from( new Set( b ));
```

[Set at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)